# set background color: Android

Tags: java, android, colors, background

How Do I set the background color of my android app. When I try:

```
LinearLayout li=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
li.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#rrggbb"));
```

My app always crashes. Could someone help me out. Thanks

Comment: why it crashes? what does logcat says? I believe that it is due to something else, like for example, do you set a layout to your Activity by using `setContentView` method ?

Comment: Do you actually use `Color.parseColor("#rrggbb")` ? You should use hex there

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> ```
> Color.parseColor("#rrggbb")
> ```

instead of `#rrggbb` you should be using hex values 0 to F for rr, gg and bb:

e.g. `Color.parseColor("#000000")` or `Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")`

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp)

From documentation:

> public static int parseColor (String colorString):
>
> Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the
>   string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception.
>   Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green',
>   'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray',
>   'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuschia',
>   'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'purple', 'silver', 'teal'

So I believe that if you are using `#rrggbb` you are getting **IllegalArgumentException** in your logcat

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29)

Alternative:

```
Color mColor = new Color();
mColor.red(redvalue);
mColor.green(greenvalue);
mColor.blue(bluevalue);
li.setBackgroundColor(mColor);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717977/android-i-have-error-with-exception-color-parsecolor)

Answer (score 29):

This question is a old one but it can help for others too.

Try this :

```
    li.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

    or

    li.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.red));

    or

    li.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(226, 11, 11));


    or
    li.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
li.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.red); //or which ever color do you want
```

EDIT: Posting logcat file would also help.

Comment: mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

Answer (score 2):

By the way, a good tip on quickly selecting color on the newer versions of AS is simply to type #fff and then using the color picker on the side of the code to choose the one you want. Quick and easier than remembering all the color hexadecimals. For example:

```
android:background="#fff"
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to set the background color of an element using Java, not XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int R = 111;    //My be assigned dynamic value
        int G = 111;    //My be assigned dynamic value
        int B = 111;    //My be assigned dynamic value
        
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(R, G, B));
```

Comment: Easy to use to change complete background-screen.

Comment: Try to not write only the code as answer but also explain it at least briefly as well