# click on a button and change the color on half of the screen

Tags: javascript, android, button, colors

So, i have 1 screen that is cut in 2 parts. First part contain 4 buttons(red, blue, green, purple) and the second is an empty space.
What i want is, when i press 1 of the button, i want to color that corresponds to show up in the empty space.

how do i create the connection between the buttons and the empty space

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Red"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Blue"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Green"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Purple"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:id="@+id/bg2"
    android:background="@drawable/selector">


</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you made some java class to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onCreate add

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
RelativeLayout rel =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bg2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);           
           }
        });
```

Comment: im getting an error saying that "symbol cannot be resolved" for bg2 and Color.Red

Comment: Oh yeah my bad it's RED not Red. And bg2 is suppose to be the id given in your xml file.
Maybe you have to import import android.widget.RelativeLayout; and import android.graphics.Color;

Comment: I don't know, just check your layout, there is a RelativeLayout with the id "bg2"

Comment: the problem was "bg2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); ". The solution is rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); . Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should create two fragments in this activity , and create a meme two relate this two fragment, so this two fragments can communicate
and then you can send and receive data between the two fragments

Comment: No need of 2 fragments can be done in 1 fragment using layouts

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question:

[set background color: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033260/set-background-color-android)

You basically follow the same steps, except you invoke the corresponding setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("xyz")); 
to the button's color as the button's onClick() is invoked.